Getting url from a google drive link and playing the audio with flutter just_audio
I tried to play an audio file stored in a google drive, while the url is passed into the just_audio package plugin, to play the audio directly from the url link. But I keep getting an error. Below is the code and the error...
// ignore_for_file: library_private_types_in_public_api, avoid_print

import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

class HymnTune extends StatefulWidget {
  final String hymnMusicPath;
  const HymnTune({super.key, required this.hymnMusicPath});

  @override
  _HymnTuneState createState() => _HymnTuneState();
}

class _HymnTuneState extends State<HymnTune> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController iconController;
  bool isPlaying = false;
  double iconSize = 30.0;
  final AudioPlayer hymnTunePlayer = AudioPlayer();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    iconController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
    );
    loadMusic();
  }

  Future<void> loadMusic() async {
    if (widget.hymnMusicPath.isNotEmpty) {
      try {
        await hymnTunePlayer.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(widget.hymnMusicPath)));
      } catch (e) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Error loading audio source: $e",
          textColor: Colors.white,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black45,
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
          gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        );
      }
    }
  }

  Future<bool> checkInternetConnection() async {
    var connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
    return connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.none;
  }

  void showNoInternetToast() {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: 'No Internet Connection',
      textColor: Colors.white,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black45,
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => animateIcon(),
      child: AnimatedIcon(
        icon: AnimatedIcons.play_pause,
        progress: iconController,
        size: iconSize,
      ),
    );
  }

  void animateIcon() async {
    if (widget.hymnMusicPath.isNotEmpty) {
      bool isConnected = await checkInternetConnection();

      if (!isConnected) {
        showNoInternetToast();
        return;
      }

      setState(() {
        isPlaying = !isPlaying;
      });

      if (isPlaying) {
        await iconController.forward();
        await hymnTunePlayer.play();
      } else {
        await iconController.reverse();
        await hymnTunePlayer.pause();
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    hymnTunePlayer.dispose();
    iconController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

the error:
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9612):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:549)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9612):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9612):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9612):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:559)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9612):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:376)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9612):       ... 7 more
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9612):   Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket is closed
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9612):       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket$SSLInputStream.read(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:551)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9612):       at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:136)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9612):       at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9612):       ... 21 more
E/AudioPlayer( 9612): TYPE_SOURCE: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
I/ExoPlayerImpl( 9612): Release 59b3258 [ExoPlayerLib/2.18.7] [Infinix-X626B, Infinix X626B, INFINIX MOBILITY LIMITED, 28] [goog.exo.core, goog.exo.exoplayer, goog.exo.decoder, goog.exo.datasource]
I/ExoPlayerImpl( 9612): Init a576746 [ExoPlayerLib/2.18.7] [Infinix-X626B, Infinix X626B, INFINIX MOBILITY LIMITED, 28]
D/ViewRootImplToast: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
D/Surface ( 9612): Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x72d948e000)
D/OpenSSLLib( 9612): OpensslErr:Module:30(110:); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/fipsmodule/cipher/cipher.c ;Line:563;Function:EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length
W/RenderThread( 9612): type=1400 audit(0.0:1891): avc: denied { search } for name="battery" dev="sysfs" ino=6960 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c118,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs_batteryinfo:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
D/Surface ( 9612): Surface::connect(this=0x72d948e000,api=1)
D/Surface ( 9612): Surface::disconnect(this=0x72d948e000,api=1)
D/View    ( 9612): [Warning] assignParent to null: this = android.widget.FrameLayout{212b1d2 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-525,73}

If you are trying to play remote audio, you can try this.
Uri.decodeFull(widget.hymnMusicPath);

